# Accessing ECS instances from AWS Lambda running in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-vpc

I am running a Lambda function in a VPS and have been able to connect to my S3 and RDS resources. However I cannot connect to containers I have running in the VPC through ECS (These containers are exposed to the internet via ELB).

I am aware that accessing the internet via a Lambda function in a VPC requires a managed NAT Gateway (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/) but is it possible to connect to EC2/ECS resources in a VPC without the NAT gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- use an internal ELB instead of a internet-facing ELB (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-internal-load-balancers.html)
- use a NAT Gateway to access the internet-facing ELB